# Position of Footer is Constant

Tags: html, css

How can I get my footer to be at the bottom of the container, after everything in main?

Here's the [site](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/122695/ds/index.html): (It's fine on the homepage, but not on any of the others)

Comment: the problem is with the height element in .bodytext. I keep that height to keep the border a certain height. How can I set the height of the border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems in your layout. You must first get rid of fixed heights or increase them as much as possible. Here is the rule that has the problem:

```
.panels h6 {
  border-left: 1px dotted;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 11px;
  height: 200px;
  /* height 200 px is less than the required height which should be ~244px */
  line-height: 1.3;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Next step is optional but recommended to prevent further problems: Inside all elements that contain multiple floated elements, add the following after all floated elements:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

This will automatically set the height of that element.

Edit ----

Set `.panels h6 { height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll; ... }`. Then use JavaScript to get and set the height of all three columns equal to the height of tallest column. You can use [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) functions such as [Element.getHeight( )](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/getheight) and [Element.setStyle( )](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/setStyle) to do this.

Alternately, google "CSS Faux Columns" or "CSS Equal Height Columns".

Comment: yea that's the problem. I set the height to be 200px so that the left border would be uniform. Is there any way I can set the border to be a certain height?

Answer (score 1):

is this solve your problem ?

```
.footer { clear:both !important;}
```

Comment: this should work, but you have to move the footer outside the #container you slider contains absolute position divs.

.footer { width: 960px;text-align:center;margin: 3em auto;}

Comment: when I do that it puts the footer in the middle of the page for whatever reason

Comment: ok.. try this, put <br clear="all" /> just before footer div.

Answer (score 1):

Remove height: 200px from .panels h6. IT should work for you.

Comment: Yes, there's an h6 overflowing and clear: both will not solve it.
I unchecked the height: 200px from my DOM inspector and it worked exactly they way you want it.

Comment: yea you're right, that problem was in bodytext as well. It was the fixed height. Thanks. How can I get the border to be a set height?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a **sticky footer**. Google for it and you will find a bunch of different options. This is what I use [link text](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/.)

Comment: I don't want the footer at the bottom of the page always, I just want it at the bottom of the content

Answer (score 0):

Use [clearfix](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200603/new_clearing_method_needed_for_ie7/) on your main div.

Answer (score 0):

i'e used [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) to solve this problem before